# Количество сколько байтов в поле mysql таблицы

Tags: mysql, sql, char

```
  CREATE TABLE `NewTable` (
  `usname`  varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL
  )
  ENGINE=InnoDB
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
  ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT
  ;
```

Если в поле будут введены не utf-8 символы, то максимум 32 символа можно хранить в этом поле.

А если в поле будут utf-8 символы, то и utf-8 можно 32 шт сохранять в этом поле.

Сколько байт будет занимать поле если в нем только utf-8 символы?

И сколько байт, если на utf-8 символы будут хранится  в нем?

Режим traditional как-то влияет на это?

---

Изменил заголовок: добавил слово "сколько" - для автопоиска, если кто-то будет задавать схожий вопрос.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Циферка в скобках `varchar` указывает именно число символов используемой кодировки. Длина в байтах напрямую зависит от используемой для поля кодировки `CHARACTER SET`.

Для `utf8` `mysql` использует максимум 3-байтовое представление. Поэтому `varchar(32)` будет занимать до 3 * 32 = 96 байт сами данные, плюс 1 или 2 байта на хранение длины данных в байтах. 96 меньше 255, поэтому требуется 1 байт. Итого такой `varchar` будет занимать от 1 до 97 байт на диске.

Интересный момент, что в индексе и всяких сортировках/группировках в памяти это поле всегда развёрнуто до максимальной байтовой длины.

Внимательный читатель может удивиться ещё одному моменту - ведь `utf` может занимать до 4 байт. А `mysql` под `utf8` умеет хранить только 3 байта. Да, `utf8` в остальном мире и `utf8` в `mysql` - разные вещи. При попытке записать 4-байтный `utf8` (именно в 4 байте размещены модные нынче смайлики, т.е. это совсем не экзотика мёртвых языков, а реально встречаемые данные) `mysql` вернёт ошибку и ничего не запишет. Для полноценного `utf8` в `mysql 5.5` добавлена кодировка `utf8mb4`.

А `utf8mb4` использует уже до 4 байт на символ. Что немного изменяет результат байтовой длины: 32 символа будут занимать до 32*4 = 128 байт, плюс один на хранение длины строки.

Comment: ого, про 4 байта на символ я не знал.

Comment: traditional  не влияет на это аж никак (я о своем вопросе, а не о вашем ответе)?

Comment: Эм.. Но в utf8 символ может занимать до 6 байт...

Comment: @Qwertiy, у вас данные о старом стандарте utf. Когда-то да, в utf8 могли существовать 5 и 6 байтовые символы. Актуальный стандарт - только до 4 байт.

Comment: Какую-нибудь ссылку можно?

Comment: От traditional, видимо, будет как раз зависеть поведение mysql при попытке записать 4-байтовый utf8 символ в 3-байтовую utf8 кодировку mysql.

@Qwertiy, цитируя мануал mysql "An older standard for UTF-8 encoding, RFC 2279, describes UTF-8 sequences that take from one to six bytes. RFC 3629 renders RFC 2279 obsolete; for this reason, sequences with five and six bytes are no longer used." http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html

Comment: "От traditional, видимо, будет как раз зависеть поведение mysql при попытке записать 4-байтовый utf8 символ в 3-байто..." - вот это интересно!

Comment: Я предполагаю, что разница будет в том, вернёт ли mysql ошибку на попытку записи или просто выбросит такой символ. Но проверить сейчас не могу, да и скорей всего надо проверять на разных версиях субд. mysql 5.7 по поведению довольно сильно отличается от предыдущих релизов.

Answer (score 0):

Количество занимаемых байтов в данном случае будет на 1 больше байтового представления хранимой строки. Грубо, если в строке 2 символа однобайтовых и 2 двухбайтовых, то нужно 7 байтов. Подробнее см. на http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html

И да, если используются корейские/китайские/японские символы, то может быть и 3 байта на символ. Об этом см. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html